# How to check if a (CSS) file exists in a MVC View

Tags: css, razor, view, asp.net-mvc-5

In my layout View (_Layout.cshtml) I need to use a css file depending on the current client. If the client specific css doesn't exist, I need to use a default css. I currently have below code, but can't get it working. What am I doing wrong ?

```
<head>
    if (@System.IO.File.Exists("@ViewData['client_dir']/client.css") {
        <link href="@ViewData["client_dir"]/client.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    } else {
        <link href="/content/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    }
</head>
```

Value of ViewData item is "/Data/Client-1".

Resulting html :

```
if (False {
    <link href="/Data/Client-2/client.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
} else {
    <link href="/content/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
```

I also tried this :

```
@{
    if (System.IO.File.Exists("ViewData['client_dir']/client.css")) {
        <link href="@ViewData["client_dir"]/client.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    } else {
        <link href="/content/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    }
}
```

Then the resulting html always contains this :

```
        <link href="/content/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

So I guess "@ViewData['client_dir']/client.css" needs to be something else ?

Comment: What is not working? (and what is the value of `ViewData['client_dir']`?)

Comment: Value of ViewData item is "/Data/Client-1".

Comment: The following appears in the html source :

    if (False {
    <link href="/Data/Client-1/client.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    } else {
    <link href="/content/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    }

I also tried with below, then nothing appears in the resulting html :
@{
            if (System.IO.File.Exists("ViewData['client_dir']/client.css")) {
                <link href="@ViewData["client_dir"]/client.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            }
        }*@

Comment: For a start it needs to be `@if (System.IO.File.Exists(String.Format("{0}{1}", ViewData['client_dir'], "/client.css")) {`

Answer (score 0):

thx Stephen, I solved it like this :

```
@{
    var cssFile = String.Format("{0}{1}", ViewData["client_dir"], "/css/client.css");
    var absolutePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(cssFile);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(absolutePath)) {
        <link href=@cssFile rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    } else {
        <link href="/content/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    }
}
```